# Javascript checkboxes incorrect calculating

Tags: javascript, checkbox, sum

Hey guys i have 6 checkboxes and am using their "rel=" values to add up and display a total sum. However if I check box 1 and 3 and 6 the addition ignores box 3 and does not add it to the sum. So basically the lowest and highest checboxes checked are adding up rather than all that are checked.

Wondering if anyone can spot a reason why.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function recalculate() {
        var sum = 0;
        var base = 0;
        var d=new Date();
        var theDay=d.getDay();
        switch (theDay)
        {
            case 6:
              base = 30;
            break;
            case 0:
              base = 30;
              break;
            default:
            base = 49 ;
        }

        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
             sum = parseInt($(this).attr("rel")) + base;
        });

        $("#output").html(sum);
    }

    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        recalculate();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, you need to change this line:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
  sum = parseInt($(this).attr("rel")) + base;
});
```

To this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
  sum += parseInt($(this).attr("rel")) + base;
});
```

With your current code, the sum isn't actually being calculated, since every time you get the `rel=` value for the next checkbox, you're overwriting the previous sum value.

**EDIT:** If you don't want to add the base each time, you can simply move that assignment out of the loop. Like this:

```
sum = base;
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
  sum += parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
});
```

Comment: This will add `base` each time as well :)

Comment: @no.good.at.coding - Good call, updated my code. Edit: D'oh our code is the same! :-P

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting the value of `sum` each time in the `each()` loop. This is what you can do:

```
 sum = base;
 $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
     sum += parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
        recalculate();
    });
```

rel attribute is for anchor tag

and instead of rel attribute use value or id

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the sum for each checkbox in the code below:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
     sum = parseInt($(this).attr("rel")) + base;
});
```

Comment: You need to move the +base out of the each loop.